# Sending a JSON from ios sender to receiver-app with the GoogleCast-SDK v3

Tags: ios, json, chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing an ios sender and custom-receiver app with the **`Google-Cast-SDK v3`**.

I can't seem to find the appropriate method to send a message containing a `JSON` to the Receiver-App. Do I have to use the `sendTextMessage`-function or is there a better way?

Would this "new" function be able to send a `base64` coded image? (The Backend has no real file-management yet and this is all I can work with right now.)

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to create a [GCKCastChannel](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_channel) instance (for your namespace), and use [sendTextMessage](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_channel.html#a536d42cdfb9d56d9ed10c3f75c493985), that is the correct way.

You could also push a base64 string via the same method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @albert-hildenberg
Could you please let me know how to receive the message from cast receiver?

Comment: @PrplRugby
How do I receive messages from the receiver in sender iOS app. I am trying to use the Cromecast Sample in Swift where it is using the GCKCastChannel subclass, there its implemented the "didReceiveMessage" is this the right way?

Comment: You can either subclass GCKCastChannel if you need something more complex, or use [GCKGenericChannel](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_generic_channel) and receive the message's via it's [delegate](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_generic_channel_delegate-p).

Once you've created your Channel, add it to the CastSession, examples here:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_advanced